# How to use constant value in UDF of Spark SQL(DataFrame)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which includes `timestamp`. To aggregate by time(minute, hour, or day), I have tried as:

```
val toSegment = udf((timestamp: String) => {
  val asLong = timestamp.toLong
  asLong - asLong % 3600000 // period = 1 hour
})

val df: DataFrame // the dataframe
df.groupBy(toSegment($"timestamp")).count()
```

This works fine.

**My question is how to generalize the UDF `toSegment` as**

```
val toSegmentGeneralized = udf((timestamp: String, period: Int) => {
  val asLong = timestamp.toLong
  asLong - asLong % period
})
```

I have tried as follows but it doesn't work

```
df.groupBy(toSegment($"timestamp", $"3600000")).count()
```

It seems to find the column named `3600000`.

Possible solution is **to use constant column** but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit()` to create the constant column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.groupBy(toSegment($"timestamp", lit(3600000))).count()
```

Comment: The lit function works great if you have a string or int to pass in.  Fails miserably with something like an Array/List.  Any ideas on what to do there?

Comment: That package also has a function called `array()` that you may be able to use to combine a bunch of literal columns -- I haven't tried it. It may not be too hard to create an analogous function for lists, especially if you look at the implementation of `array()` in [functions.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala) -- one doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Now having tried using `array()`, I should point out that the corresponding UDF parameter needs to be of type `ArrayBuffer[T]` for some `T`.

Comment: **Spark 1.5.0 Note:** Passing `array()` now seems to result in a `WrappedArray` being passed into the UDF.  This means you can make the UDF parameter type be something like `Seq` or `IndexedSeq`.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov Do you know how to pass map? I am not able to pass map to udf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598890/spark-udf-how-to-pass-map-as-a-parameter

Comment: @nir Are you looking for a function that would construct a map from pre-existing columns, or do you want to simply pass a column that already contains a map? I don't think the former exists, but the latter should be more a matter of "how do you access it inside the UDF?" or "how do you declare the UDF?" rather than "how do you pass it?" You may want to post a new question showing what you're trying to achieve, and link to it here.

Comment: @SpiroMichaylov I think it's former that I am looking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598890/spark-udf-how-to-convert-map-to-column?noredirect=1#comment68442055_40598890. I have a temp workaround by converting map to array first and then pass array as a udf parameter. I can't use clouser as I am running interactive shell.